# Getting data from sql into drop down list(select\option in html)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a drop down element in html, and to add the values according to user pre-choice.
Lets say I have table with one col is game type ans second is a name field.
So if the user first drop down choice is basketball - so another drop down list is opened with all the basketball fields as options.

so I have my html file which has inside this php lines:

```
$game_type = $_POST['gameType'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Jbtraining1");
if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_sport",$con);
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM fields WHERE game_type = '$game_type'");
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<option value='".$row['field_name_en']."'>" . $row['field_name_en'] . "</option>";
?>
</select>
```

but this lines does not work. I think most of the lines work well cause if i chage this line:

$game_type = $_POST['gameType'];

to let say to this line -

$game_type = "basketball";

It does work just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure that you're actually posting in `gameType`? You should also look at moving away from using `mysql_*` functions - as it stands, your script is open to SQL injection,

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Put an echo on `$_POST['gameType']` before you assign it to a variable and check if a value was posted correctly

Comment: RedFilter - The new drop down list is appearing blank.

Comment: jlc007 - Thanks but it doesont the answer - it says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport_site\BuyerDirected.php on line 58"

Answer (score 0):

Change your file extension from `.html` to `.php`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  echo $_POST['gameType'];
```

to see if the variable is send.

It sounds like it isn't send because you say it works when you use:

```
 $game_type = "basketball";
```

If the echo is empty something gos wrong when you send the variable.

If that is the case post the code you use to post the variable.